# Why is the object I add to my ngModel in angular showing up as undefined when passed through console.log?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, loops, directive

I have two directives in my angular app.

Directive 1 has an ngModel that is an array of objects.
Through the directive methods, I am pushing an object to the end of the array.

So for example, the original ngModel array is [1,2,3,4], and I am adding, 5 so the array looks like [1,2,3,4,5].

This ngModel gets passed as the ngModel to my second directive. I can console.log the array and see all 5 items, but when I try to access the last item, the item that I added, it does not show up. For example, if I do a foreach on the array, it's like the last item doesn't exist.

I cannot access the item. Anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Would be able to help if you show up your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use the `link` function to add the fifth item in your parent directive.

There are two types of `link` functions: `pre` and `post` link. Let's say you have `parent` and nested `child` directive. The link functions are going to be called in this order:

- parent pre-link
- child pre-link
- child post-link
- parent post-link

By default if you use `link` in you directive object notation, it will be the post-link function.

```
return {
   link: function (scope, element, attrs) { }
}
```

And if you add your fifth element in the parent post-link, then it will not be available for the child, as it will be added after the child link has been called. The way to give properly initialized data to the child is either to use pre-link or controller (but the latter is out of scope here).

```
return {
    link: {
        pre: function (scope, element, attrs) { }
    }
}
```

Here is a working plnkr with your example: http://plnkr.co/edit/24KrGLdnkDCrLr2SzXhQ?p=preview